# Which one is correct? "stop doing a habit?" or "stop making a habit?"

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs, collocations

Please help me clear up my confusion..

I haven't got the foggiest idea if my following phrases are correct,
"this term is used to stop doing something, especially ***stop doing a bad habit***."

I think that this statement is already good in its nature, but at the same time, I feel like nobody uses this phrase.

What else I have in mind is  "this term is used to stop doing something, especially ***stop making a bad habit***."

I don't want to pair up the word "break" with a habit because my students' English skills are very basic. I would like to pair "stop + gerund + a bad habit." What best verb do I need to use?

Comment: Once you have a bad habit you can stop it, but you can also take action to avoid developing a bad habit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend '**give up** a bad habit'. You don't 'do' a habit, you 'have' one.

Comment: Yes. The opposite of 'pick up' or 'acquire [a bad habit]'. But we'd not say 'He's picked up smoking / etc'. And you 'stop smoking / etc' but not 'stop a bad habit'.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need make or do or any other verb. Just say "stop a bad habit".

Comment: If I embed this phrase, the sentence becomes "this term is used to stop doing something, especially stop a bad habit." Want to clarify if this sentence is correct, then?

Comment: It would be stopping because you are referring to the action as a noun.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, Hot Licks wrote:

> Stop practicing a bad habit.